# angular directive is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a text box and a  directive to restrict showing negative values in on the screen, and the ng-model should contain that negative value.

In the below directive I am always getting `""` as the value for **inputValue**, How to get the ng-model value for the **inputValue**

```
 app.directive('numberOnly', function () {

  return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
          modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {
              if (inputValue == undefined) return '';
              var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
              if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
                  modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                  modelCtrl.$render();
              }
              return transformedInput;
          });
      }
  };
});
```

Comment: Because you need to set `ng-model="inputValue"` on the element that uses the directive.

Comment: ohh, it's fine but in this directive it is just removing the - infront of the value, but not it is hiding the negative value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works well:

## HTML

```
<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" number-only ng-model="model"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

## JS

```
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);

module.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = '01234';
}]);

module.directive('numberOnly', function() {

  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
        // Value prints here
        console.log(inputValue);
        if (inputValue == undefined) return '';
        var transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        if (transformedInput != inputValue) {
          modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
          modelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return transformedInput;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

## Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/bdmqxr5y/720/

Comment: Okay, but it is not hiding the negative values, it's just removing the minus before the value

Comment: this fiddle is working fine, thanks but this directive is not hiding the negative values

Comment: is it possible to achieve this functionality

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tplawyer/bdmqxr5y/728/

you can use `transformedInput ` instead of `inputValue`

Comment: still it is just removing the minus but not hiding the value